# Windows remote connection looping MSTSC

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, remote-desktop, mstsc

I built a program that will connect to a list of remote machines through Windows. The only issue I'm having is that after it connects to the Remote Desktop the Windows command prompt is in a "frozen state" until I disconnect from the remote. At the point it loops the code back where you can select another machine.

I want it to be able to loop back without having to disconnect so I can connect to multiple machines.

Here is my code:

```
:deployCode
cmdkey /generic:"SERVERNAME" /user:"user" /pass:"password"
mstsc /v:"SERVERNAME"
cls
goto :machinelist
```

It doesn't step through the cls clear command and go back to my machine list (`goto :machinelist`) until I close the server I connect to.

I tried using "&" to join the two commands but that did not work.

i.e `mstsc /v:"SERVERNAME" & goto :machinelist`

How can I step to cls and goto :machinelist without having to disconnect after mstsc?

Comment: Please wrap your .bat in "code" style (by adding 4 spaces at the start) it will be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

mstsc does not return if within a script. Prefix by "start" it will work (just tested here)

```
:deployCode
cmdkey /generic:"SERVERNAME" /user:"user" /pass:"password"
start mstsc /v:"SERVERNAME"
cls
goto :machinelist
```